# Splitting strings & Pattern matching in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a following String:

```
MYLMFILLAAGCSKMYLLFINNAARPFASSTKAASTVVTPHHSYTSKPHHSTTSHCKSSD
```

I want to split such a string every time a `K` or `R` is encountered, except when followed by a `P`.

Therefore, I want the following output:

```
MYLMFILLAAGCSK
MYLLFINNAARPFASSTK
AASTVVTPHHSYTSKPHHSTTSHCK
SSD
```

At first, I tried using simple `.split()` function in java but I couldn't get the desired result. Because I really don't know how to mention it in the `.split()` function not to split if there is a `P` right after `K` or `R`.

I've looked at other similar questions and they suggest to use Pattern matching but I don't know how to use it in this context.

Comment: Are they `**K**`, `**P**` etc as text? Or did you put them in bold for us to see them?

Comment: No I just made them in bold so that you could see

Comment: You can check your string manually, e.g. with `charAt()` if it contains K or R alone and then use `substring()` and the positions found to split your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this regexp:

```
(K)([^P]|$)
```

and substitute each matching by

```
\1\n\2
```

as ilustrated in the following [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Km7ror/1).  No negative lookahead needed.  But you cannot use it with split, as it should eliminate the not `P` character after the `K` also.

You can do a first transform like the one above, and then `.split("\n");`
so it should be:

```
"MYLMFILLAAGCSKMYLLFINNAARPFASSTKAASTVVTPHHSYTSKPHHSTTSHCKSSDK"
    .subst("(K)([^P]|$)", "\1\n\2").split("\n");
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use split:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=[KR])(?!P)");
```

Because you want to *keep* the input you're splitting on, you must use a *look behind*, which asserts *without* consuming. There are two look arounds:

- `(?<=[KR])` means "the previous char is either `K` or `R`"
- `(?!P)` means "the next char is *not* a `P`"

This regex matches *between* characters where you want to split.

---

Some test code:

```
String str = "MYLMFILLAAGCSKMYLLFINNAARPFASSTKAASTVVTPHHSYTSKPHHSTTSHCKSSD";
Arrays.stream(str.split("(?<=[KR])(?!P)")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
MYLMFILLAAGCSK
MYLLFINNAARPFASSTK
AASTVVTPHHSYTSKPHHSTTSHCK
SSD
```

Comment: After many many reading about **negative lock-ahead assertion** I now realize how can that be useful. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, your answer has helped me a lot